# How to add dockerhub credentials on Jenkins?

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

How to add docker hub credentials on Jenkins? Here i am providing:
Username:dockerhub_15
password:************
ID:?(which id I have to provide?)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZy4d.png

Answer (score 0):

Like written in the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/):

"In the ID field, specify a meaningful credential ID value - for example, jenkins-user-for-xyz-artifact-repository. You can use upper- or lower-case letters for the credential ID, as well as any valid separator character. However, for the benefit of all users on your Jenkins instance, it is best to use a single and consistent convention for specifying credential IDs."

So you can put whatever you want there. If you want to use your Credential within a scripted pipeline for example, you can then use this ID to reference your credentials.

In your case putting "DockerRegistryCreds" as value could make sense for example.